# Changing string to ascii in python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, decode, encode

I need to convert word

```
name = 'Łódź'
```

to ASCII characters

```
output: 'Lodz'
```

I can't import any library like unicodedata.
I need to do it in clear python.
I've tried to encode than decode and nothing worked.

Comment: If you really cannot import any library even from the standard library, and need a general solution, you will need to reimplement large parts of `unicodedata` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple method would be to map and replace. This also does not require any special imports.

```
name = 'Łódź'
name=name.replace('Ł','L')
name=name.replace('ó','o')
name=name.replace('ź','z')
print(name)
```

Comment: I wanted a prettier one and not like that